# Custom PC won't boot

Tags: power-supply, power, computer-building, desktop-computer, desktop-customization

Recently replaced PSU and now pressing the power button gives less than a second of light, as well as psu and cpu fans spinning ~ one revolution before stopping again.

Have tried clearing CMOS, all plugs are in correctly and securely, 8 pin to cpu and 20 pin to motherboard are good, everything else worked previously but have double checked all cables anyway. Please post any ideas and I will let you know the outcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the motherboard out of the case and put it on an anti static bag.  Hook up all components now that you have a clear view of all connectors.  Things should pop into place with a satisfying click for the most part.  Start off with just CPU and RAM installed and move your way up until you figure out what is causing the power to turn off.  It could be something as dumb as a screw in contact with a trace on your motherboard, could be a faulty PSU.

Comment: @Richie086 thanks for the response, will take me a while so will get back to you when I can.

Comment: Let me know if that works or if you run into any snags along the way.

Comment: many motherboards use a 24 pin connector, and many power supply's accommodate this by having a motherboard power connector extension (google 20+4 motherboard connectors). Make sure you are using a 12 volt rail for the CPU adapter (the PCI-E 8 pins look similar, and might fit) other than that, does your motherboard have an error system (some have LED digit readouts that will show post codes, or a system of beeps)? understanding why your PU is failing is a very good way to stop it :-P

Comment: Hi all, my mistake, I was using a 24 pin to motherboard, didn't mean to say 20. Managed to get it to boot with only motherboard/processor powered. Will continue to add drives and case peripherals until the problematic component is isolated. Will update later.

Comment: Fixed! Eventually I discovered that the old cables were somehow tripping the system. After replacing all old cables with new ones that came with the new PSU, it works perfectly! Reminder to anyone changing PSU: Use the new cables! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Eventually I discovered that the old cables were somehow tripping the system. After replacing all old cables with new ones that came with the new PSU, it works perfectly! Reminder to anyone changing PSU: Use the new cables! Thanks for your help!